# Reminder notification when button clicked after few hours/minutes

Tags: javascript, python, java, html, frontend

Need some help on javascript button
My use case:
Need a button like thing where when we click the button it should get time out for 30min with a notification/ a sound. And it should get autoreset because we need to use this button multiple times in day. I've a python script which can remember me but needed this usecase in real time to implement other code.
Is there any possible way to do this and can someone help me in achieving this?

Any help is much appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you need 30min it will be 1 800 000 ms(1 sec = 1000ms > 30min = 1800sec = 1 800 000ms)

```js
 function myFunction(){
  var audio = new Audio('https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/cc0-audio/t-rex-roar.mp3');
  audio.play();
};
```

```html
<button onclick="setTimeout(myFunction, 3230)">test</button>
```